# Google Drive API 404 error with fileId

Tags: api, oauth, google-drive-api

I'm trying to delete a file using the Google Drive API v3 and HTTP requests. I can successfully create a file and get its ID. But my DELETE request is giving me a 404 error.

Here's my request

```
curl -i \
    -X DELETE \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.Ci-wA7am5SyJOiuu4nduvWv47DpHN6dpS7RjapS7cwT9hvQsUwh-9rT0QcJzvQ2UhQ" \
   "https://googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9U3n669ikqSOHg2eDE5LVN3cUk"
```

I made sure that the file ID is valid.

In the google playground, I can make the request work only if I select the "Delete file" operation from the "list possible operations" menu. If I try a DELETE call with the url the request will fail with a 404 error.

I get 404 in any query where a parameter is fileId. I feel like there's an issue with the token and maybe with file ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Error [404](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/handle-errors#404_file_not_found_fileid) means that the user does not have read access to a file or the files does not exist.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "message": "File not found {fileId}"
      }
    ],
    "code": 404,
    "message": "File not found: {fileId}"
  }
}
```

Suggested action: Report to users that they do not have read access to the file or that the file does not exist. Tell them that they should ask the owner for permission to the file.